# How to make grouping through several associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6, pg-search

There is such a chain: Blog <-> Posts -> Comments.

But the Post may be in two or more Blogs. That is, the connection between Blog and Post is many-to-many.

I need to implement a search by comments, and group the result by blog.

I try to do in this way:

```rb
Comment.search_by_query(search_params[:query])
       .joins(post: :blogs)
       .group('blogs.title')
       .limit(20)
```

I get an error and fix it this way:

```rb
Comment.search_by_query(search_params[:query])
       .joins(post: :blogs)
       .group('comments.id, blogs.title')
       .limit(20)
```

And after that I get a new error (but similar to the previous one):

```
> ERROR:  column "pg_search_9780daa5e89d610e876399.rank" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ..."blog_id" GROUP BY comments.id, blogs.title ORDER BY pg_search_...
```

This is about the [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) gem. The `search_by_query` method was created using `pg_search_scope`:

```rb
pg_search_scope :search_by_query, against: %i[title]
```

If I add the `rank` column, there will be no more errors, but there will be no grouping either:

```rb
group('comments.id, blogs.title, rank')
```

I will get an array of comments.

Tell me, please, how can I group the comments by blogs?

Comment: I guess you might have already tried `group_by`?

Comment: @Gautam `group_by` method will work with the result. But I still want to understand how to implement this on the SQL (ActiveRecord) side.